# Why the bin bag in Silver Linings Playbook?

Tags: props, silver-linings-playbook

The hero of *Silver Linings Playbook*, Pat, was seen wearing a bin bag (or garbage bag depending upon your locale) that had holes cut for his head and arms...

[image]

Both his mother and father asked why he was wearing a bin bag, but this was never resolved.  I don't know the reason for it.  I suppose it provides protection from the rain, but it never rained in the film.

What is the meaning of Pat wearing a bin bag?  Is it a habit endemic to Philadelphia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Costume designer Mark Bridges explained: “It was in the original
> material, the book by Matthew Quick. It really sums up that
> working-class world, and also [Cooper’s character’s] dedication to try
> to get back into shape to win his life back by any means
> necessary—even by looking ridiculous and causing complete humiliation
> to the whole family by running down the street like that.”
>
> He also told, “The garbage bag was actually made so that it would
> be silent. We needed to wire the microphone on Bradley so that you
> would not hear the crinkle, crinkle, crinkle of a real garbage bag. It
> sort of had a silencer on it.” Asked how many garbage-bag costumes
> were made in total, Bridges tallied “five of six, just in case
> something happened. I have one in my garage, actually, just in case we
> need to do a reshoot or something.”
>
> Source : [vanityfair.com](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2013/02/bradley-cooper-silver-linings-playbook-garbage-bag)

It also help in [weight loss](http://www.broadwayworld.com/bwwfitness/article/ASK-A-TRAINER-Why-Do-People-Wear-Garbage-Bags-in-the-Gym-20130829), as per claims.